# Why do I get different predict results between Xgboost's python and CLI version?

Tags: python, shell, machine-learning, xgboost

Recently,when I try to use xgboost's CLI version to predict the inputs I found its results is much different from the python version.

With python,I predict it like this:

```
data = xgb.DMatrix(X)
bst = xgb.Booster()
bst.load_model(modelfile)
leafindex = bst.predict(data, pred_leaf=False)
```

And use CLI as below:

```
./xgboost xgboost.conf task=pred model_in=../models/gb.model_depth4_150trees_2016-07-02
```

here is my configuration file:

```
# General Parameters, see comment for each definition
# can be gbtree or gblinear
booster = gbtree
# choose logistic regression loss function for binary classification
objective = binary:logistic

# Tree Booster Parameters
# step size shrinkage
eta = 1.0
# minimum loss reduction required to make a further partition
gamma = 1.0
# minimum sum of instance weight(hessian) needed in a child
min_child_weight = 1
# maximum depth of a tree
max_depth = 4

# Task Parameters
# the number of round to do boosting
num_round = 150
# 0 means do not save any model except the final round model
save_period = 0
# The path of training data
data = "agaricus.txt.train"
# The path of validation data, used to monitor training process, here [test] sets name of the validation set
eval[test] = "agaricus.txt.test"
# The path of test data
test:data = "data"
```

Python input data format:

```
8       201     1       2       26      10000.0 8589934592      32      0       0       1000000.0       0
2       3       1       1       50      10000.0 8589934592      32      524288  8       1000000.0       0
2       3       2       2       19      10000.0 8589934592      512     512     8       1000000.0       0
4       24      1       1       23      10000.0 8589934592      8192    0       0       1000000.0       0
1       2       2       3       50      10000.0 8589934592      32      512     8       1000000.0       0
21      1       2       3       48      10000.0 8589934592      32      512     8       1000000.0       0
5       12      1       2       42      10000.0 137438953472    32      512     8       1000000.0       0
2       11      2       2       86      10000.0 0       0       0       0       1000000.0       0
1       10      2       8       99      10000.0 8589934592      32      65536   8       1000000.0       0
2       11      2       8       97      10000.0 8589934592      32      65536   8       1000000.0       0
4       5       1       1       4       10000.0 1073741824      32      0       0       1000000.0       0
...
```

CLI input format:

```
0 1:8 2:201 3:1 4:2 5:26 6:10000.0 7:8589934592 8:32 9:0 10:0 11:1000000.0 12:0
0 1:2 2:3 3:1 4:1 5:50 6:10000.0 7:8589934592 8:32 9:524288 10:8 11:1000000.0 12:0
0 1:2 2:3 3:2 4:2 5:19 6:10000.0 7:8589934592 8:512 9:512 10:8 11:1000000.0 12:0
0 1:4 2:24 3:1 4:1 5:23 6:10000.0 7:8589934592 8:8192 9:0 10:0 11:1000000.0 12:0
0 1:1 2:2 3:2 4:3 5:50 6:10000.0 7:8589934592 8:32 9:512 10:8 11:1000000.0 12:0
0 1:21 2:1 3:2 4:3 5:48 6:10000.0 7:8589934592 8:32 9:512 10:8 11:1000000.0 12:0
0 1:5 2:12 3:1 4:2 5:42 6:10000.0 7:137438953472 8:32 9:512 10:8 11:1000000.0 12:0
...
```

The results of python version:

```
0.138298
0.00288907
0.0114002
0.0477143
0.00185653
0.00455882
0.000503023
0.000817317
0.00332584
0.00178041
0.0666806
0.03003
...
```

the CLI version:

```
0.000100178
0.201246
0.449562
0.0506984
0.451953
0.389587
0.034748
0.992795
0.00348666
0.00661674
0.0186095
0.0260032
0.996163
0.259104
0.552341
0.972762
...
```

I used the same model file, and the CLI version got 40% value higher than 0.5,that was not in accordance with our expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

It seems that the model file trained by the python and the cli can't be used by each other.
And when use the model trained by each self the results still have a little difference like these:

```
by python       by cli
0.169874        0.222063
0.999997        0.999554
0.00454239      0.000879413
0.0140518       0.00824018
0.0148116       0.00859811
0.000353913     0.000880754
0.0207635       0.019058
0.000916939     0.000579058
0.00109237      0.000286653
0.00247333      0.00272115
0.0650928       0.0319875
0.946068        0.965301
0.997704        0.999615
0.987644        0.991665
0.997242        0.984403
0.948666        0.909703
0.000781899     0.00079996
0.000319449     0.000138011
0.0400793       0.164134
0.00216081      0.000781626
0.023867        0.0323994
```